# @Singleton annotated class creates multiple instances with Dagger2 in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, singleton, dagger-2

I have a class annotated with @Singleton like this:

```
@Singleton
class SomeClass @Inject constructor() { ... }
```

and I use it in other classes like this:

```
class OtherClass {
  @Inject 
  lateinit var someclass: SomeClass
  init { DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this) }
}

@Component
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
  fun inject(otherClass: OtherClass)
}
```

But I get different instances in every class I inject SomeClass into. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `DaggerAppComponent.create()` in the `OtherClass` `init{}` block you always creating a new `DaggerAppComponent` with each `OtherClass` instance.
You should cache your component in your application scope to make those `@Singleton` annotation be effective for you.

I think the `Application` class is a good place to do that. You can find a small example [here](https://github.com/overheadhunter/daggerfx).

Comment: It is not an android app. So is there a best practice to cache the component in this case ?

Comment: On what kind of platform are you using Dagger 2?

Comment: a JavaFX app with kotlin